# EAGLE Multiple PCB layouts

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

In EAGLE, i have one schematic and want to create two PCB designs (SMD and TH versions of the same board). Is it possible somehow to have two PCB layouts exisitng in the same project (based on one shared schematics)?

I'm using v9.6.2

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this because the package type for the board layout must be consistent with the package selected in the schematic.

You could create say the PTH version, then make a copy of the schematic under a new name. In the copy of the schematic you can change the package of, or replace each component you wish to be SMD.